# Sticky mouse when dragging controls in VS2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005

Maybe this is a dumb question, but I have the following behavior in Visual Studio 2005 while designing forms:

1 - Drop a control onto the form (suppose it's a Label, just for discussion)

2 - Drag that label to a specific location (aligning w/other controls, whatever)

3 - Release the mouse button

4 - The control is still stuck to the mouse!!!

To get it un-stuck from the mouse, I have to hit ESC, which restores the Label to it's original location.

This is driving me nuts.  I literally have to use the arrow keys to move each control into place, pixel-by-pixel.  I don't observe this behavior anywhere else in VS2005, nor do I observe it in the OS in general.

I am running on Windows XP inside a Parallels Virtual Machine, hosted on OS X.  I don't think there is a driver problem though, b/c as I already said, no other apps demonstrate anything like this.

Please tell me there is some tiny checkbox buried somewhere that will turn off this behavior.

Comment: I sometimes get this sort of behaviour when my wireless mouse is running low on power and it flickers on and off. Not saying that's what's happening, but my best guess is that for some reason the window isn't recieving the mouseup messages.

Comment: I do have a wireless mouse; I'll replace the battery and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem spread to other applications within my VM, so I reinstalled Parallels tools and it went away.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have ClickLock enabled (or a similar feature). Try this:

Go to Control Panel in Windows
Open the Mouse control panel
Go to the Activities tab
Deselect ClickLock

If that doesn't work, maybe you have a similar feature in OS X?

Comment: I've checked that, and besides, wouldn't that affect all my apps, not just the VS2005 forms designer?

I'll double-check when I get home tonight though.

Comment: Yes, it would. There wasn't an indication of whether you experienced it elsewhere or not, so I thought it may help. If you're only experiencing it in this single scenario, then this is, of course, not the issue.